# A difficult same color Bishop endgame

Tags: endgame, bishop-endgame

Is this position a White win or a draw?

```
[Title "Black to move : "]
[FEN "3B4/5p1p/4k1p1/2b1P3/8/5P2/1P4PP/5K2 b - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: In John Speelman's "Endgame Preparation", a very similar endgame is discussed (with an "a" pawn instead of a "b" pawn if I recall correctly) with the result being a win

Answer (score 0):

It is a draw.

```
[Title "Black to move : "]
[FEN "3B4/5p1p/4k1p1/2b1P3/8/5P2/1P4PP/5K2 b - - 0 1"]

1... Bd4 2. b3 Bxe5 3. h3 Kd5 4. Bb6 Kc6 5. Ba5 Kb5 6. Be1 f5 7. Ke2 Kc5 8. Kd3 Bf6 9. Bc3 Be7 10. Bd2 Bf6 11. Bc3 Bd8 12. Bd2 Bf6 13. Be3+ Kb4 14. Kc2 Bg7 15. Bd2+ Kc5 16. Bc1 Kb4 17. Bd2+ Kc5 18. Bg5 Be5 19. Be3+ Kb4 20. Bd2+ Kc5 21. Bc3 Bg3 22. Kd3 Bh4 23. Bd4+ Kb4 24. Kc2 Bg5 25. Be5 Kc5 26. Kc3 Be7 27. Bg7 Bd6 28. Bd4+ Kb5 29. Be3 Be5+ 30. Bd4 Bd6 31. Bf6 Kc5 32. Bg5 Be5+ 33. Kd3 Kb4 34. Kc2 Kc5 35. Be3+ Kb4 36. Bd2+ Kc5 37. Ba5 Bf6 38. Kd3 Bg7 39. g4 Bf6 40. gxf5 gxf5 41. Bc7 Bg7 42. Ke3 Bh6+ 43. Kd3 Bg7 44. Ba5 Bf6 45. Bd2 Bg7 46. Bc3 Bf8 47. Be1 Bg7 48. Bc3 Bf8 49. Bd2 Bg7 50. Bg5 Kb4 51. Kc2 Bf8 52. Bf6 Bd6 53. Bc3+ Kc5 54. Bg7 Kb4 55. Bc3+ Kc5 56. Bh8 Kb4 57. Bb2 Be7 58. Bg7 Bd6 59. Bf6 Bf8 60. Bc3+ Kb5 61. Bd2 Be7 62. Kc3 Bf6+ 63. Kd3 Kc5 64. Kc2 Kb5 65. Bf4 Kc5 66. Bb8 Bd8 67. Be5 Kd5 68. Bc3 Kc5 69. Kd3 Be7 70. Bg7 Bd6 71. Bh6 Kb4 72. Kc2 Kc5 73. Kd3 Kb4 74. Kc2 Kc5 75. Kc3 Be7 76. Be3+ Kb5 77. Ba7 Bf6+ 78. Bd4 Be7 79. Bg7 Kc5 80. Be5 Bf8 81. Bg3 Bg7+ 82. Kd3 Bf8 83. b4+ Kxb4 84. Kd4 Be7 85. Ke5 Kc4 86. Kxf5 1/2-1/2
```

Comment: Is the result the same under ICCF rules , and not FIDE rules ? It requires the 50 move rule Is abolished for positional with 7 Pieces or less. In practice , It requires considering all results from Syzygy tablebases that lead ti a mate as wins , even cursed wins. It happens more often that people think that a position results in a draw under FIDE rules but a win under ICCF rules ( there are already a fair number of similar cases in the TCEC). What happens under ICCF rules ?

Comment: @user35196 it is still a draw because black has the option of sacrificing the bishop for one of the pawns if it ever gets too close too promotion.

Comment: Final position after **86. Kxf5** is a [draw](https://syzygy-tables.info/?fen=8/4b2p/8/5K2/2k5/5PBP/8/8_b_-_-_0_1) according to the tablebase ([reason already provided](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/42528/a-difficult-same-color-bishop-endgame?noredirect=1#comment70051_42543)).